# Total Sum of each value column on sap.ui.table

Tags: sum, sapui5

I need to show the total sum of each column that have values on it. But I only can use the sap.ui.table for this.

I look for so much in internet but only found old results with deprecated functions.

Someone can help me, please?

The example that I need to reproduce:
[image: total sum example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUyRH.png)

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using Fiori Elements (e.g. Analytical List Page), you can use:

```
@DefaultAggregation: #SUM
```

on the amount field exposed through the consumption CDS View.

It should automatically show the total sum of the column in the footer of the table.

Comment: Please read "[Link-only answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info)"
and "[…barely more than a link to an external site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)"

Comment: Read, edited my answer just now. It is better ?

Comment: The community will say.